# Number of 3 colorings on grid with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, coloring

I am trying to figure out a way to do the following:

Given a $3 \times n$ grid, ($n \geq 2$) choose coloring by using $3$ colors (say, RGB), such that

1. any given column cannot have all grids of same color (i.e., no RRR in any single given column),
2. a given row (which is of length $n$) cannot have all the same color.

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle and basic combinatorial principles seems like the right approach, but I am not sure of the pattern.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion seems like the right way to go.  Just off the top of my head, it seems easy to do it if we ignore condition 2.  So, I would try to do that, and then subtract the cases where condition 2 is violated, but condition 1 is fulfilled.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate. Thanks for marking this as such.